# Initialize a matrix (that is, a list of lists) in Python

Tags: python, list

I wish to initialize a list of lists using something like `[[0]*n]*n`. But something happened that I don't quite understand -- see the interactive `iPython` session below for my problem:

```
    In [1]: a=[[0]*3]*3

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

In [3]: a[1][1]=3

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [[0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 3, 0]]
```

==> WHY setting `a[1][1]` resulted in the above?
(That is, it is setting the whole COLUMN to 3)

```
In [5]: b=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

In [6]: b
Out[6]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

In [8]: b[1][1]=3

In [9]: b
Out[9]: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

==> That is working fine!

Comment: It's due to references / pointers to the initial list which got dupplicated via the multiply but at the end of the day, each sublist is just the same initial list. This is a dupplicate question, but I am still trying to find the question....

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer -- and for finding the duplicate question!